# Natbib sorting and citation order by appearance in lyx

Tags: lyx, citing, apa-style

I am wondering how I can change the order of the citations in my paper. They are appear in alphabetical order however I want to be in the order that I selected.
(Note: I am not asking about order of the references and I know that should be alphabetically ordered). Could you please help me to fix this .. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which bibliography style do you employ at the moment? (The tag "apa-style" is currently set; it would be helpful if you confirmed that this is indeed the bibliography style you're interested in.) Separately, have you already tried using the `unsrt` bibliography style? Since the title of your posting suggests that you use the `natbib` citation management package, you could also give `unsrtnat` a try.

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift reply. I have tried apacite and unsrt and some others. Indeed when I used unsrt it make the order of my in-text citation as I wish. I need to make the alphabetical  order in the references but unsrt is unsorted the list of references in bibliography section. How can I have chronological order in in-text citation and alphabetical order in bibliography?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your objective in my first comment. If I'm correct in assuming that you're using the `natbib` package, you could try loading it with the option `compress`, i.e., as `\usepackage[compress]{natbib}`. Doing so will suppress sorting of the cited entries.

Comment: I added \usepackage [compress]{natbib} but I got this error:  "The package natbib has already been loaded with options:
  [longnamesfirst,sort]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [compress]
Adding the global options:
  longnamesfirst,sort,compress
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed." and I don't know how can I change the default options in natbib.

Comment: Thanks for this information. It would appear that your document, or one of the packages that your document loads, has already loaded the `natbib` package with the option `sort` before LaTeX gets to your new instruction, `\usepackage [compress]{natbib}`. Can you find that instruction that loads `natbib` with the `sort` option and comment it out (or delete it entirely)? It needs to be removed, since you want to *disable* the sorting of citation items, right?